# Accidentally deleted login.keyring and user.keystore - any recourse?

Tags: google-chrome, files

As the title states - I accidentally deleted the two files above and now Chrome is unable to sync when I open it. I've tried to <kbd>Add password keyring</kbd> in the Password manager application, but it does not allow me.

It seems that the `user.keystore` file was automatically replaced, however it is empty.

What should I do to be able to have my chrome settings stored locally again? The files I `rm`'d were in `~/.local/share/keyrings`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are those files for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a new profile for "Chrome", it should work however if you want to recover the files then:

First install `testdisk`:

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

Then run it:

```
sudo testdisk
```

From the Items select "Create", then select your home partition, select "None" then "Advanced" and move the selected item on list:

[image]

Now it lets you to go into directories, go to the `~/.local/share/keyrings` and see if it show "keyrings" file to you:

```
Directory /ravexina/.local/share

 drwxr-xr-x  1000  1000      4096 18-May-2017 22:44 .
 drwxr-xr-x  1000  1000      4096 11-May-2017 20:59 ..
 drwxr-xr-x  1000  1000      4096 12-May-2017 12:11 xorg
>drwx------  1000  1000      4096 11-May-2017 21:26 keyrings
```

Press <kbd>c</kbd> to recover it.

Comment: Hey! Perfect, this worked! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that It was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try extundelete and hope they haven't been overwritten. boot from a live CD if you have it to minimize the chance of the files being overwritten.

To install:

```
sudo apt install extundelete
```