# How can I recover files I deleted with find ... -delete?

Tags: command-line, files, data-recovery, find

By mistake, perform the following command:

```
find ./ type f "*.jpg" -delete
```

My intention was to delete all the .jpg files, but instead deleted everything that was there. My question is if there is any way to recover those files or in which directory they will be now, because in the recycle bin they are not.

The correct command was:

```
find ./ type f name "*.jpg" -delete
```

Comment: If you want to recover deleted files, you should shutdown and not use the drive until you are ready to do recovery work. It is particularly important to avoid mounting the drive. Instead you should boot the computer from another drive, for example an Ubuntu live drive (DVD, USB pendrive, memory card) made from an Ubuntu iso file. See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986: 
Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files

Comment: I disagree Zanna. The command will first delete the content of . and then show a lot of errors, 1 of which is 'cannot delete ./'. Sorry VipPunk, but I think your files are gone. I hope you have a backup??

Comment: Btw for future reference - to avoid these specific kinds of problems, first run the find command in a way that you **display** the filtered files rather than **delete** right away. Then youll see from the output if your command works as you thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `find ./ type f name "*.jpg" -delete` what you did was searching in this paths:

```
./
type
f
name
"*.jpg"
```

and then `find` runs a `-delete` on everything that was found.

What you can do is use recovery tools like `testdisk` and `photorec`. Logically your files are gone, however they just have been unlinked (but their data still occupies disk space). I suggest you to use `testdisk` utility to recover them - it should work fine for you.

I wrote an answer to recover a single file [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926762/accidentally-deleted-login-keyring-and-user-keystore-any-recourse/926773#926773). You can also have access to `testdisk` step by step guide [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Comment: @VipPunkJoshersDroopy, I think **photorec** might help you recover files.

Comment: @sudodus there is no point in using a **file carver** if the files are only unlinked and can selectively be restored easily with a file system-aware tool.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, please tell us which system-aware tool you recommend.

Comment: @sudodus not "system", "file system"-aware. Also, Testdisk is already written in the accepted answer so there was no need for me to mention it again. :) Or, if we are talking about NTFS, RecuperaBit (but it's not the case here, it seems).